# Best way to track (direct) file downloads

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess, statistics

What is the best method to track direct file downloads?

Google Analytics only works with javascript, can't track direct file downloads.

Best would be a secure and own hosted solution.

Comment: What protocol is this over?  wont your logs tell you everything you need to know?

Comment: Get a log analyzer and pull the direct-download URLs out of your access_log?

Comment: Apache log is not very user friendly and I want to show the counter on my site later.

Comment: See also: https://dave.autonoma.ca/blog/2023/11/12/php-download-hit-counter/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Feel free to use :)

**.htaccess:**

```
RewriteEngine on    
RewriteRule ^(.*).(rar|zip|pdf)$ http://xy.com/downloads/download.php?file=$1.$2 [R,L]
```

**mysql:**

```
CREATE TABLE `download` (
    `filename` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `stats` int(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY  (`filename`)
)
```

**download.php**

```
<?php

mysql_connect("localhost", "name", "password")
or die ("Sorry, can't connect to database.");
mysql_select_db("dbname"); 
$baseDir = "/home/public_html/downloads"; 
$path = realpath($baseDir . "/" . basename($_GET['file'])); 

if (dirname($path) == $baseDir) {
if(!is_bot())
mysql_query("INSERT INTO download SET filename='".mysql_real_escape_string(basename($_GET['file']))."' ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE stats=stats+1");


header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . basename($_GET['file']));
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($path));
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
ob_clean();
ob_end_flush();
readfile($path);    
}

function is_bot()
{

    $botlist = array("Teoma", "alexa", "froogle", "Gigabot", "inktomi",
    "looksmart", "URL_Spider_SQL", "Firefly", "NationalDirectory",
    "Ask Jeeves", "TECNOSEEK", "InfoSeek", "WebFindBot", "girafabot",
    "crawler", "www.galaxy.com", "Googlebot", "Scooter", "Slurp",
    "msnbot", "appie", "FAST", "WebBug", "Spade", "ZyBorg", "rabaz",
    "Baiduspider", "Feedfetcher-Google", "TechnoratiSnoop", "Rankivabot",
    "Mediapartners-Google", "Sogou web spider", "WebAlta Crawler","TweetmemeBot",
    "Butterfly","Twitturls","Me.dium","Twiceler");

    foreach($botlist as $bot)
    {
        if(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],$bot)!==false)
        return true;    // Is a bot
    }

    return false;
}

?>
```

Comment: With newer versions of MySQL will probably use [mysqli_connect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php) and [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) instead

Answer (score 6):

Your apache logs should contain a lot of info, but I think what you're asking for is more control over what gets logged and when. So what you want to do is have two pages: one with the link to the file, and the other that tracks the file, like so:

**file_page.php**

```
<a href="download.php?id=1234">Download File!</a>
```

**download.php**

```
<? // Code to track the file using PHP, whether that means storing data in a database, saving to a log, or emailing you. I'd use a DB, like so:

   // Prep the vars
   $file_id = $_GET['file_id']; // You should sanitize this first.
   $file_path = '/files/'.$file_id.'.pdf';

   // Save data to database
   mysql_query('INSERT INTO download_log
      SET file_id = '.$file_id.',
          date_downloaded = '.date('Y-m-d H:i:s').',
          user_id = '.$_SESSION['user_id']);

   // Now find the file and download it
   header('Content-type: application/pdf');
   header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$file_id.'.pdf); // or whatever the file name is
   readfile($file_path);
```

Something like that, anyway.

The page will be blank when it is done, but all browsers should begin downloading the file when the page is loaded.

So what I'm doing here is I'm saving the file ID, the current datetime, and the user ID of the person downloading it (from a $_SESSION variable). You probably want to store a lot more information, such as the user's IP address, the HTTP_REFERRER or other $_SERVER information, so you can track where the user came from and when and what they downloaded.

Good luck.

Comment: This will work. However, keep in mind if you have large files you are sending through `readfile` and you have a busy site, this will consume lots of RAM.

Comment: @MichaelIrey, Are there any other methods of tracking file downloads with low RAM consumption?

Answer (score 1):

Two modifications I have made on the original answer in order for the code to work with PHP7.3 , Mysqli and Mariadb engine:

1. For me, "mysqly_real_escape_string" did not work, so instead I used "basename($_GET['file'])"

2: Mariadb SQL does not accept "SET" after "UPDATE" thus i used "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE  stats = stats + 1"

As a result I have posted a new question here:[Download counter for direct download links using .htaccess, mysql and php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57092732/download-counter-for-direct-download-links-using-htaccess-mysql-and-php)

See full code below...

```
<?php

$conn =  mysqli_connect('localhost', 'user_name', 'password','database');
if (!$conn) {
      die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$baseDir = '/home/user/domains/mydomain.com/public_html/downloads'; 
$path = realpath($baseDir . '/' . basename($_GET['file'])); 

$file = basename($_GET['file']);// this is what I used instead mysqli_real_escape_string
$sql = 'INSERT INTO downloads VALUES ("'.$file.'", 1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE  stats = stats + 1';

//***************************************************
// following SQL line inserts record with empty filname field value but updates the counter as it is supposed to:
// $sql = 'INSERT INTO download  VALUES ('.mysqli_real_escape_string(basename($_GET['file'])).", 1)' ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE stats=stats+1";
//**********************************************************


if (dirname($path) == $baseDir) {
if(!is_bot())
mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
mysqli_close($conn);
header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . basename($_GET['file']));
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($path));
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
ob_clean();
ob_end_flush();
readfile($path); 

}

function is_bot()
{

    $botlist = array("Teoma", "alexa", "froogle", "Gigabot", "inktomi",
    "looksmart", "URL_Spider_SQL", "Firefly", "NationalDirectory",
    "Ask Jeeves", "TECNOSEEK", "InfoSeek", "WebFindBot", "girafabot",
    "crawler", "www.galaxy.com", "Googlebot", "Scooter", "Slurp",
    "msnbot", "appie", "FAST", "WebBug", "Spade", "ZyBorg", "rabaz",
    "Baiduspider", "Feedfetcher-Google", "TechnoratiSnoop", "Rankivabot",
    "Mediapartners-Google", "Sogou web spider", "WebAlta Crawler","TweetmemeBot",
    "Butterfly","Twitturls","Me.dium","Twiceler");

    foreach($botlist as $bot)
    {
        if(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],$bot)!==false)
        return true;    // Is a bot
    }

    return false;
}


function alert($msg) {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$msg');</script>";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Me too have made some improvement on the original code posted here.
I've added some additional stats such as country, region, latitude, and longitude, to name a few...

here's the updated code:

```
<?php

$conn =  mysqli_connect('localhost', 'aeon_dl_usr', 'Turions@1522','aeon_downloads');
if (!$conn) {
      die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

if($_GET['f']=="workbook"){
    $file="work_log_book_public.pdf";
}else{
    die("File not found.");
}


$baseDir = substr(__FILE__,0,strpos(__FILE__,"downloads"))."downloads/"; 
$path = realpath($baseDir . '/' . $file); 

$ipAddress=get_client_ip();

$geo = unserialize(file_get_contents("http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip=".$ipAddress));
$User_Ipaddress=$geo["geoplugin_request"];
$User_Country = $geo["geoplugin_countryName"];
$User_City = $geo["geoplugin_city"];
$User_Region = $geo["geoplugin_region"];
$User_CurrencySymbol = $geo["geoplugin_currencySymbol"];
$User_CurrencyCode = $geo["geoplugin_currencyCode"];
$User_Latitude = $geo["geoplugin_latitude"];
$User_Longitude = $geo["geoplugin_longitude"];


$sql = 'INSERT INTO downloads VALUES ("'.$User_Longitude.'", "'.$User_Latitude.'","'.$User_CurrencyCode.'","'.$User_CurrencySymbol.'","'.$User_Region.'","'.$User_City.'","'.$User_Country.'","'.$User_Ipaddress.'", "'.$file.'", 1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE  stats = stats + 1';


if (dirname($path) == $baseDir) {
    if(!is_bot()){
        mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
        mysqli_close($conn);

        header("Cache-Control: public");
        header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$file);
        header("Content-Length: ".filesize($path));
        header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
        ob_clean();
        ob_end_flush();
        readfile($path); 
    }
}else{
    die("error on loading file");
}



function is_bot(){
    $botlist = array("Teoma", "alexa", "froogle", "Gigabot", "inktomi",
    "looksmart", "URL_Spider_SQL", "Firefly", "NationalDirectory",
    "Ask Jeeves", "TECNOSEEK", "InfoSeek", "WebFindBot", "girafabot",
    "crawler", "www.galaxy.com", "Googlebot", "Scooter", "Slurp",
    "msnbot", "appie", "FAST", "WebBug", "Spade", "ZyBorg", "rabaz",
    "Baiduspider", "Feedfetcher-Google", "TechnoratiSnoop", "Rankivabot",
    "Mediapartners-Google", "Sogou web spider", "WebAlta Crawler","TweetmemeBot",
    "Butterfly","Twitturls","Me.dium","Twiceler");

    foreach($botlist as $bot)
    {
        if(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],$bot)!==false)
        return true;    // Is a bot
    }

    return false;
}


function alert($msg) {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$msg');</script>";
}


function get_client_ip() {
    $ipaddress="";
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED']))
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED'];
    else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR']))
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED']))
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'];
    else if(isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']))
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    else
        $ipaddress = 'UNKNOWN';

    return $ipaddress;
   
}


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

after struggling with above code for a while, I decided to post my working version as well, it can save a lot of time for you all!!

First of all make sure your caching is disabled when you're playing with code like this... I was wondering for a while why I was making changes but always my old (bad) results were coming back.... Eventually I had to go in my webhost's admin panel, go to performance & caching and disable Varnish, go to PHP settings and disable opcache. I also added some lines to the top of my PHP to also tell it not to cache... afterwards troubleshooting went a lot better :)

**MySQL:** (I have a slightly different table so I'll post the structure as well)

```
CREATE TABLE `downloads` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `filename` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `stats` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

ALTER TABLE `downloads`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `filename` (`filename`);

ALTER TABLE `downloads`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
COMMIT;
```

**download.php**:

```
<?php
header("Expires: Tue, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT");
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$baseDir = "/data/sites/web/www/WHEREEVERYOUHAVEYOURFILESLOCATED"; 
$path = realpath($baseDir . '/' . basename($_GET['file'])); 
$file = basename($_GET['file']);

$mysqli = new mysqli("YOURDATABASESERVERNAME", "DBUSERNAME", "DBPASSWORD", "DATABASENAME");
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO downloads (filename) VALUES (?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE  stats = stats + 1");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $file);
$stmt->execute();

if (dirname($path) == $baseDir) {
if(!is_bot())
header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . basename($_GET['file']));
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($path));
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
ob_clean();
ob_end_flush();
readfile($path); 

}

function is_bot()
{

    $botlist = array("Teoma", "alexa", "froogle", "Gigabot", "inktomi",
    "looksmart", "URL_Spider_SQL", "Firefly", "NationalDirectory",
    "Ask Jeeves", "TECNOSEEK", "InfoSeek", "WebFindBot", "girafabot",
    "crawler", "www.galaxy.com", "Googlebot", "Scooter", "Slurp",
    "msnbot", "appie", "FAST", "WebBug", "Spade", "ZyBorg", "rabaz",
    "Baiduspider", "Feedfetcher-Google", "TechnoratiSnoop", "Rankivabot",
    "Mediapartners-Google", "Sogou web spider", "WebAlta Crawler","TweetmemeBot",
    "Butterfly","Twitturls","Me.dium","Twiceler");

    foreach($botlist as $bot)
    {
        if(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],$bot)!==false)
        return true;    // Is a bot
    }

    return false;
}


function alert($msg) {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$msg');</script>";
}
?>
```

As you can see this is a mix of all above solutions with some lines added to it. I'm new to PHP so I'm not claiming I know it all, just trying to help out where I can. I hope this helps...

**Usage**:

```
https://www.yoursite.com/download.php?file=yourfilename.txt
```

Comment: Have you ever heard of **SQL injections**?

Comment: edited after @YourCommonSense's objection