# Detect if user downloads with php and html

Tags: php, html

I build a internet site with php and html. I detect the access from the users with a code like this :

```
    $qry ="SELECT * FROM visit WHERE ip='" .$ip ."' AND date(quando)=CURRENT_DATE";
    $arr=$dbcls->query_arr($qry);
        
    if(count($arr)==0)
    {
        $data=get_location2($row["ip"]);
        if($data)
        {
            $country=$dbcls->escape_string($data->country);
            $sub=$dbcls->escape_string($data->subdivision);
            $city=$dbcls->escape_string($data->city);
            $qry="INSERT INTO visit(ip,n,country,region,city) 
            VALUES('" . $ip ."',1,'".   $country. "','" . $sub . "','". $city. "');";
            
            //echo $qry;
        }
        else    
            $qry="INSERT INTO visit(ip,n) VALUES('" . $ip ."',1);";
    }
    else 
        $qry="UPDATE visit SET n=n+1 WHERE ip='" . $ip ."' AND date(quando)=CURRENT_DATE ;";
    $dbcls->query_command($qry);
```

that allow me to save all the users that login in my site. The next step is to save how many users downloads my program.
The question is: how can I detect when a user make a download with php? If I have to create code  with Javascript How can access to my database with javascript?

Comment: How are you currently serving the file? Eg. is it a download link to static file or are you calling a special `download.php` for example?

Comment: with  this instruction **<a  href="downloads/Treebase.zip" download>Treebase</a>**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8155652/best-way-to-track-direct-file-downloads

Comment: The link from @MrUpsidown gives you answers. Flagged to be closed as duplicate. - Alternate approach could be to send an AJAX request to your server when someone clicks the link.

Answer (score 0):

Your URL downloads/Treebase.zip is not served by PHP, is a static file.

The download is managed by the web server not by PHP.

To manage by PHP you'll need to make a route and make the PHP send the file.

Something like downloads/download.php?file_name=Treebase.zip.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).